# Azure Connection Can Not Connect Certificate Error

Tags: java, azure, adal4j

I am having a hard time trying to authenticate against a particular Tenant ID of Azure. The code that I am using is the following one:

```
public abstract class Azure
{
    private final static String GRAPH = "https://graph.windows.net/";
    private Logger objLogger;
    private String strAccessToken;
    private String strTenantID;
    private String strLogin;
    private String strAuthorize;
    private String strGraph;
    private String strApplicationID;
    private String strUsername;
    private String strPassword;
    public String getAccessToken() throws InvalidKeyException, MalformedURLException, ServiceUnavailableException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException
    {
        if (this.strAccessToken == null)
        {
            this.setAccessToken();
        }
        return this.strAccessToken;
    }
    private void setAccessToken() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException, ServiceUnavailableException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException
    {
        AuthenticationContext objContext;
        AuthenticationResult objToken;
        ExecutorService objService;
        Future<AuthenticationResult> objFuture;
        objService = null;
        objToken = null;
        try
        {
            objService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
            objContext = new AuthenticationContext(this.getAuthorize(), false, objService);
            objFuture = objContext.acquireToken(GRAPH, this.getApplicationID(), this.getUsername(), this.getPassword(), null);
            objToken = objFuture.get();
            this.getLogger().info("Connection to Azure ".concat(this.getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase()).concat(" successfully stablished"));
        }
        finally
        {
            objService.shutdown();
        }
        if (objToken == null)
        {
            throw new ServiceUnavailableException("Authentication Service is not available");
        }
        this.strAccessToken = objToken.getAccessToken();
    }
    public void setGraph()
    {
        this.strGraph = GRAPH.concat(this.getTenantID());
    }
}

public class Connection1 extends Azure
{
    private static Connection1 objInstance;
    private Connection1() throws ParameterException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException
    {
        super();
        this.setTenantID(<Tenant ID>);
        this.setLogin("https://login.microsoftonline.com/".concat(this.getTenantID()));
        this.setAuthorize(this.getLogin().concat("/oauth2/authorize"));
        this.setGraph();
        this.setApplicationID(<Application ID>);
        this.setAccessToken(null);
        this.setUsername(<username>);
        this.setPassword(<password>);
        this.setLogger();
    }
    public static Azure getInstance() throws ParameterException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException
    {
        if (objInstance == null)
        {
            objInstance = new Connection1();
        }
        return objInstance;
    }
}
```

I have two classes Connection1 and Connection2.
Connection2 is a copy of Connection1, the only things that I changed are:

1) Tenant ID

2) Application ID

3) Username

4) Password.

With Connection1 I am able to authenticate and retrieve the data without any issues.
The issue comes with Connection2, with this one I get the following error:

```
[pool-3-thread-1] ERROR com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext - [Correlation ID: 63cc6344-2bc1-4f61-aaa0-a2f07acb172b] Execution of class com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AcquireTokenCallable failed.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

It seems to be a certificate error, so I research a little online, and they recommend to add ***"DigiCert Baltimore Root"*** certificate to my certificate store. The certificate is already there. Do you have any idea of how should I face it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually find the issue. I used TamperData addIn of Firefox and check each redirection to get all the sites with their respective certificates. It seems that there was a change in this particular tenant that instead of using DigiCert Baltimore Root it end on Entrust.net Root

Answer (score 0):

Just according to your error information, there are two blogs below which you can refer to to fix this issue `unable to find valid certification path to requested target`.

1. https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/
2. http://nodsw.com/blog/leeland/2006/12/06-no-more-unable-find-valid-certification-path-requested-target

The above blogs all used the tool [InstallCert](https://github.com/escline/InstallCert) to server certificate that can be added to local keystore. Please follow the README of the GitHub repository.

Meanwhile, only my guess, I think a possible reason is resource competition for a certificate store  in a JVM. So if you are running `Connection1` and `Connection2` within a JVM instance, you can try to separately run them on their own standalone JVM instance, or try to copy the `JAVA_HOME` directory and set a temporary `JAVA_HOME` & `PATH` environment variables in command line to run the other `Connection2` without any resource shared with them.